# Which SemVer version to use between releases?

Tags: development-process, versioning, semantic-versioning

I'm working on a project that uses [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org). The commit history can be generalized as:

[image]

Also, the current version is present in source code (so that the software can use it for various purposes).

I'd like to start implementing a process that I've been seeing around:

- Development commits contain a version such as `x.y.z-dev`. The idea is that `x.y.z` will be the next release, but we are currently developing it.
- When development is over, the in-source version becomes `x.y.z` for the one commit that is a release.
- After the release, the source code updates to use a new `x.y.z-dev` version.

This allows the software as seen on development commits to not erroneously suggest that it represents a release version.

**The issue I'm running into is knowing which version to increment to *after a release*.** [Semantic Versioning has requirements](https://semver.org/#summary) for what kinds of changes can be found in a new version. For example, `1.0.0` to `2.0.0` indicates a backwards-incompatible change has been made to some interface. But, directly after a release (when the version is incremented to a new `-dev` version), it's hard to say what kinds of changes will be included in the future for the *next* release.

For example, if we just released `1.2.3`, incremented to `1.2.4-dev`, and then introduce a backwards-incompatible change, `1.2.4-dev` is now invalid and should be `2.0.0-dev`.

Should I just do another increment to the next `-dev` major version during the development cycle when we notice that such a change has occurred? It seems iffy that commits would then exist with a version that would never be released.

Comment: Damn good question! After the time goes by can you give a short report about your experience with the solution of your choice please? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mu. Releases have versions. Commits do not have versions. Version numbers are assigned during the release process. At least as far as SemVer is concerned.

Adding a pre-release like `1.2.4-dev` would still be a release, albeit with special SemVer ordering semantics. But even for a pre-release: once you make the release, you're not allowed to use the version number for a different release.

Of course, this is a rather unsatisfactory response. We do want to summarize the state of the software in a single identifier, even for an unreleased development state. This is an inherent limitation in SemVer. One solution might be to use a deliberately non-SemVer label such as `dev-1234abc` where part of a Git commit ID is used in the label. One compromise could be to note that the version number is *meaningless* on unreleased project states, so that you should just build upon the previous release. One of my projects just keeps the last version numbers, and just accepts that you can't tell a dev version apart from the previous release.

Adding build information to a SemVer number could help, though the build information is ignored by SemVer ordering semantics. For example, you might add a Git hash like this to the previous release: `1.2.3+git.1234abc`. This would give you a somewhat useful label, but this shouldn't be mistaken for a true SemVer number because it was not assigned to a release.

Comment: I'm happy with this answer because it shows that my expectations for SemVer were incorrect. We had been persisting the last released version in our source code during development, and I think I'll just stick with that and note this in the project documentation.

Comment: This answer just about covers it. The only potential thing to consider is taking it a step further and _enforcing_ that the versioning is part of the release process, rather than living in the source code. You can use combinations of things like [Conventional Commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/) and other structured commit messages, tags, and branches to be able to generate version information in files without ever committing a version string.